# getShippingIncludeTax - the right way to code

Tags: php, magento

Im building a webshop on Magento Platform  (still localhost) and would like to have the shipping displayed in my header cart.

Currently the shipping rate is shown okay in the main cart but in the header cart it's displayed withouth tax.

This is the code of the main cart: ( the right one with tax included)

```
<?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getShippingIncludeTax()) ?>
```

This is the code of the header cart: ( displayed without tax)

```
<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingAmount(); ?>
```

As you can see the "getShippingIncludeTax" should be added instead of just the amount. 
Any ideas how to implement this code together?

Extra: 
This code also works for the header, but has the same amount withouth tax.

```
<?php $totals = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getTotals();
        if(isset($totals['shipping']))
        print __(number_format($totals['shipping']->getDat('value'),2)); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

would that be better ?

```
<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingIncTax(); ?>
```

It's actually rather easy to see whats inside your object and what you can ask from it

```
<?php print_r(array_keys(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getData()));?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this has changed, but in Magento 1.7 I had to use getShippingInclTax() rather than getShippingIncTax().